# Transmitting json on to browser

Tags: node.js

On the client side i generating this json using javascript from the form elements.

```
var ServerUser = [];

var inputs = $('input.email'), tmp;

$.each(inputs, function(i, obj) {

  tmp = {

    'title': $(obj).attr('title'),
    'name': $(obj).val(),
    'age' : $(obj).siblings('.age').val()
  };


  ServerUser.push(tmp);

  personString = JSON.stringify(ServerUser);

  console.log(personString);


});
```

How can I transmit this information to my Node.js server? I don't want to use expressjs framework.When i submit the form on the localhost i should get a json data of email and age and title. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At your server:

```
function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var textData = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            textData += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
             var jsonData = JSON.parse(textData));
             console.log(jsonData); //This is the data you might want to parse    
        });
    }
}
```

At your client you cannot send this in form encoded format. if you send this via jquery ajax,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/your_end_point",
    processData: false, //This prevents jQuery from parsing your data
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: personString,
    success: function() { }

});
```

Comment: I am getting this error in the command prompt.                                                   var server = http.createServer(function (req,res){
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token var

Comment: @Natasha can you post it in http://jsapp.us ? or send me your id, i hate spam bots taking my mail id (if i post here) :|

Comment: ya ok..its  njnatashajain@gmail.com

Comment: Leave a trace for the ones who stumble upon this question later